# Difference between caches.match and cache.match

Tags: javascript, web-services, caching

We use `caches.match(event.request)` in the service worker to do "Cache only strategy". I noticed that we also return `cache.match('someURL')` right after then of `caches.open("cache-name")` promises. This is quite confusing.

What is the difference between `caches.match(event.request)` and `cache.match('someURL')`. What is the use case for each of it?

Example cases:

**Caches.match**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)); 
});
```

**Cache.match**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: what are `caches` and `cache`?

Comment: Without context for what `caches` and `cache` are, it's hard to say the exact difference. Still, they are two possibly unrelated objects.

Comment: Sorry if my question is quite confusing. I added example cases which uses caches.match and cache.match in Service Worker

Answer (score 7):

`cache.match` searches for an item in a *specific* cache, while `caches.match` searches *all* caches for a match.

Comment: Quoting  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/match   "caches.match() is a convenience method. Equivalent functionality is to call cache.match() on each cache (in the order returned by caches.keys()) until a Response is returned."

Answer (score 6):

I guess you didn't know that the word "caches" reffers to [CacheStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage)
Basically caches or the cache storage stores all caches while cache is just a named cache inside the cache storage. Basically caches.match should get you the instance of the cache storage while cache.match gives you the instance of a specific cache.

Comment: For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/match